# Console and downloads bar change my CSS style and HTML page appearance

Tags: html, css

My `div` elements change its position and columns color. As i think it happens if height of a window browser is changed. I thought problem can be because of `@media` queries. But it is not the reason.

Solved this problem with setting min-width.

Comment: 1. If you solved the problem with min-width, what are you asking here? 2. Could you show us examples of your code?

Comment: I asked, and then found out how to solve it, and let know guys who could be interested in helping me.